# Excel: how to use cell value as part of the other cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

> =SUM(K133:K141)

Numbers 133 and 141 are changing and are stored in some other cells, for instance, number 133 is in the cell W17.

How do I change the SUM formula to go look for starting and ending address into the content of 2 other cells?

Comment: Great, thank you!
Formula is now:

=SUM(INDIRECT("K"&W17):INDIRECT("K"&X17))

Answer (score 3):

Use the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("K"&W17):INDIRECT("K"&X17))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid using volatile functions such as INDIRECT. The following will give the same result and is non-volatile

`=SUM(INDEX(K:K,W17,0):INDEX(K:K,X17,0))`